# Is bing-search freshness for finnish-market broken?

Tags: bing-search, azure-cognitive-services

Bing web search freshness does not seem to work properly in all markets.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-web-search-api/

It works for major markets, and for swedish market. For example if you do:

"Kvinna hittad död"

and change between day, weem, month, undefined.. it brings different results and it does seem to work.

But for finnish markets:

"kiinan uudet johtajat"

It always returns the same responses no matter what freshness is.

Am I missing something or is there a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I checked again for fi-fi market and now response changes based on freshness parameter. I checked this behavior here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-web-search-api/.

I had checked this a few days back and it was not working then, so it seems this is fixed recently.

Comment: I can't reproduce that it would have been fixed. Still the same problem